# Ajax data not being sent to controller function (CodeIgniter)

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I have an anchor tag and  would like its `data-id` to be sent to a function in the controller which would in turn retrieved data from the database through the model.
However the data is not getting past the controller. The ajax response is showing that the data was sent but controller shows otherwise.

Here is my ajax code:

```
$(document).on("click",".learn-more",function(){
   var sub_item_id = $(this).data("id");
   $.ajax({
      url:"<?php echo base_url();?>Designs/business_cards",
      type:"POST",
      data:{sub_item_id:sub_item_id},
      success:function(data){
          console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(error){
        throw new Error('Did not work');
      }
   })
});
```

I had set datatype:"json" but the data was not being sent so I removed the datatype and it worked,the ajax part that is.Or atleast the response showed that data was sent.
My **controller** code is:

```
function business_cards(){
    $id = $this->input->post('sub_item_id');
    $data['quantity'] = $this->subproduct_model->get_quantities($id);
    $this->load->view('category/business-cards',$data);
}
```

My **model** code is:

```
public function get_quantities($sub_item_id){   
     $this->db->select('quantities');
     $this->db->where('id',$sub_item_id);
     $query = $this->db->get('sub_products');
     return $query->result_array();
}
```

HTML Code which includes the anchor tag

```
<?php foreach ($results as $object):?>
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-id="<?=$object['id'];?>" data-target="#pricelist-modal-2" class="learn-more">View Prices</a>
<?php endforeach?>
```

The `data-id` is displaying the correct value as per the iteration.

When I check the result array of the model code it is an empty array showing that the `$sub_item_id` was not passed in the controller. What could be the problem?

Comment: use this url:"<?php echo base_url();?>Designs/business_cards/+sub_item_id",

Comment: @MohitKumar when i add sub_item_id i get an error message

Comment: what did you try to do to troubleshoot this? please do a `echo`of the value of `$this->input->post('sub_item_id');` in `business_cards()` function, what does ajax success `console.log()` print? can you include the relevant html as well?

Comment: @emineminems the error message I am referring to is the one in the `ajax error function`. When I `echo` `$this->input->post('sub_item_id')` nothing is displayed.

Comment: Or could the problem be that I did not use `dataType:json` in my `ajax`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just copied your code and I was able to get the value in the controller. 
In your controller function do var_dump($id). Then in your developer tools (F12) check the console. Since you have console.log(data) that var_dump should be in the console. It won't show on the screen.

Some other things to check:

Does your db have records with that ID? Could your db result array be empty because it actually should be?

Are you sure that the data-id actually has a value when you click the  tag?

Comment: I was checking the var_dump on the screen and not in the console. I have seen it is returning a result in the console `array(1) {  [0]=>  array(1) {   ["quantities"]=>string(28) "200,500,1000,2000,5000,10000"}}` but when i loop through the array in my view using `foreach($quantity as $object) echo quantity['quantities']` I get no result. Is it a must I get my result in the success function of the ajax or what could be wrong with my loop??

Comment: @lorrainemutheu Yes you must use the success function. Since your using Ajax your view is not being reloaded. So you can either return the array and use append() or html() which are jQuery functions, or you could create a new view and return that to your Ajax from your controller then use html() to put it where you need it on you main view.

Answer (score 0):

it is not passed to the controller because you forgot to put a parameter inside the function of your controller.

> Note: you cannot use ***input post*** because you're not using form.

```
function business_cards($id){ //put a parameter here, serve as container of your passed variable from **ajax**
    //$id = $this->input->post('sub_item_id');
    $data['quantity'] = $this->subproduct_model->get_quantities($id); //pass the id to your model
    $this->load->view('category/business-cards',$data); 
}
```

change your ajax code to this..

```
  $(document).on("click",".learn-more",function(){
     var sub_item_id = $(this).data("id");
     $.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo base_url('Designs/business_cards/"+sub_item_id+"');?>", //pass the id here
        type:"POST",
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(error){
          throw new Error('Did not work');
        }
     })
  });
```

Comment: When I did this I got `undefined index $id` error notice on `$this->subproduct_model->get_quantities($id)` and `missing parameter` in `function business_cards($id)`

Comment: make sure that the id is not empty before passing it to your ajax.